# python function to simplify fraction

Tags: python-3.x, fractions

I am trying to write a function that will help me break down a fraction into simple components like so

[image]

I wrote this function

```
from fractions import Fraction
def lowest_fraction(frac):
    num = frac[0]
    den = frac[-1]
    if frac == (1, den):
        yield frac
    while frac != (1, den):
        new_num = num - num//2
        rem = num - new_num
        new_frac = Fraction(new_num, den)
        frac = (new_frac.numerator, new_frac.denominator)
        num = rem
        yield frac
```

I ran the below

```
for each in [(1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 8), (5, 8), (7, 8), (7, 16), (9, 32)]:
    print('{}: '.format(each))
    for k in lowest_fraction(each):
        print('\t{}'.format(k))
```

Here's the output

```
(1, 2): 
    (1, 2)
(3, 4): 
    (1, 2)
    (1, 4)
(3, 8): 
    (1, 4)
    (1, 8)
(5, 8): 
    (3, 8)
    (1, 8)
(7, 8): 
    (1, 2)
    (1, 4)
    (1, 8)
(7, 16): 
    (1, 4)
    (1, 8)
    (1, 16)
(9, 32): 
    (5, 32)
    (1, 16)
    (1, 32)
```

You can see that the output for `(3, 8)` and `(9, 32)` is not in their simplest form. I think what I want to do can be accomplished by writing a recursive code but I cannot presently write one because I don't fully grab the concept of recursion yet.

Comment: Recursion just means applying your function to an intermediate result (in this particular case).

Comment: Since you are using an iterator instead of creating a list, you will probably want to use `yield from` in case of recursion.

Comment: Also, you are not making it very clear as to whether you want this to work in the general case, or only for negative integer powers of two.

Comment: @Mad Physicist It should be for powers of 2 because I'm writing some function to parse music xml files so durations are almost always in powers of 2 like so. I know `(3, 8)` is an intermediate result. I could say `if frac[0]>1` but I don't know exactly how I could call the function back again. I'll try. And this powers of two only came to mind now that you've mentioned it.